# Gmail SMTP Authentication Error when using App password with workspace domain alias

Tags: email, gmail, google-workspace, smtp-auth, yagmail

I want to be able to use my Google Workspace email alias when automating email sending using yagmail and gmail's SMTP server.

I have set the default "Send Email As" address from the main email (@gmail.com) to the alias email (@domain.com), which is fine when sending manually. I currently have 2SV enabled with my main email & app password sending emails properly through yagmail, but it still shows the sending address as the main email. I tried authenticating with the email alias and a new app password, but I am receiving the following error:

smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted).

I tried a few solutions found online, such as this one (https://support.google.com/mail/thread/127655543/gmail-alias-not-working-it-says-the-password-i-am-entering-for-the-alias-is-wrong-but-it-s-correct?hl=en), to no avail.

Why is using App password fine for my main email but not my domain alias? How can I automate sending emails using domain alias? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!